# Get FingerPrint User ZKTEco Download and Upload Many Device

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, fingerprint

I Have an Attendance Machine iFace302, I want to Download From 5 Device simultaneously and insert the data to my local database. After that Upload it back to 5 device simultaneously, Why I do this ? because inside the machine it has their own database and I want all data inside the machine is same. So anywhere they put the finger they can access / attendance.

for now I'm using 2 programming language VB.NET(WinForm) for main Program And ASP.NET to Get User Data with webservice, it's still local(For now). Can anyone help me how to make it ?

Comment: `I want to Download From 5 Device simultaneously` were you able to do this?

Comment: can you please post the steps and SDK how you get data from ZKTeco machine into c# program ?

Comment: @ZiadAdnan, Hi Sorry for late reply. The SDK have source code how to use the Machine. Try it

Answer (score 4):

Go to this link [ZK Software Standalone SDK](https://www.zkteco.com/en/SDK). Select the SDK tab. Then download the correct SDK version for your development machine (32-bit or 64-bit). The programming reference manual is included in the RAR file.

Comment: Before asking I'm already download the SDK, all of SDK already being tested and what I want is passing data from that finger print type using website... like 1 Computer in City A to 1 Computer in City B

Comment: It is just a matter of network connectivity. If you can connect (ping) to the network of computer in City A from computer in City B then there shouldn't be a problem. If there are firewalls between the two connection, then you should open the port to the biometric devices. The port number is in the manual.

Comment: can you sir update the link I have machine uFace 800 ZKTeco I need the SDK and how to get the fingerprint data from machine to C# software can you help me please and guide me the steps ?

Comment: @ZiadAdnan check these SDK [here](https://www.zkteco.com/en/SDK)